# How to unit test .Net 6 code that calls a gRPC code first service

Tags: .net, grpc

I'm setting up a gRPC client. The scenario is I have a REST API that then calls backend services using gRPC Code First. But I can't figure out how to I can inject a mock gRPC service so I can test the code calling the gRPC service. Ideally, I'd like to setup the gRPC service in program.cs then inject it into the class library code but am open to other solutions. Any ideas?

Note the client is .Net 6 Web API.

Comment: Please add sample code here (from your project) to help our to better helping you